# I can't set cron job

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, cron

I've tried to set a cron job in *"crontab -e"*:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/testCron.php
```

*testCron.php* file creates another file, it contains only this:

```
<?php
$f = fopen('cron-' . date('H-i-s') . '.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($f, 'asdf');
fclose($f);
```

But the file *cron-....txt* doesn't appear. Were can be a problem?

---

**I did/checked this:**

- Cron is working. I checked this with sudo "service cron start" commad.
- the $PATH contains *"/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"*

Comment: Use absolute path to `testCron.php`

Comment: Where/how did you "set" that line?

Comment: @frz3993 - With absolute path is the same error

Comment: @Mat - I put " * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/testCron.php" in the console

Comment: Cron jobs are set via the `crontab` command.

Comment: Then please put "ubuntu add cron job" in google, you'll find lots of docs.

Comment: Strange, everything seems to be in order ... Have you tried just `* * * * * php /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/testCron.php` ?

Comment: You probably don't need `/usr/local/bin/php`, just `php` is enough. And please explain `console returns me:`, because I don't think running a job with cron will return anything to current console. Unless you mean that happen when you are trying to add the job to cron.

Comment: "But the file cron-....txt doesn't appear." - **Where**? *grin*

Comment: Could be a permission issue. Check if the directory ```/home/vagrant/Code/xxx``` is writable by the cron user. Try to write the file in ```/tmp``` to be sure your code works.

Comment: You changed the question substantially, but I'm going to give similar comment. Use absolute path, even in the PHP file.

Comment: `$PATH` is irrelevant, since you're not executing any commands without their full pathname.

Comment: Enable error reporting in the script with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Then check your email to see if there's any output.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the log from cron jobs to identify errors.

Depending on your system, the cron log can be located in different places. Find the files containing cron logs:

```
grep -ic cron /var/log/* | grep -v :0
./auth.log:1246
./auth.log.1:3054
./bootstrap.log:3
./syslog:187
./syslog.1:220
```

Then view the contents of the log in question, e.g. via `cat`:

```
cat /var/log/syslog
```

Or view the latest run of testCron.php in that file:

```
grep -i testCron.php /var/log/syslog | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script creates the `cron-...txt` file with no path; therefore it appears in the current directory - if it has write permission.  Cronjobs will have a different start directory - usually the user's home, but may be anywhere, depending on configuration.

Try one of these:

- Change your script to create the file in a specific directory
- Do a chdir() to set a specific current working directory
- Set a specific directory in your crontab configuration
- Look for the files in the user's home directory
- Ensure the user has write permission to the directory you are placing the files in